# iOS 8.0+ Max Length Issue

Tags: html, safari, ios8, maxlength

On iOS 8.0 devices when in Safari, users can enter additional characters to input fields with a max-length attribute.

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Create a html page with a input field that has a max-length attribute
2. Navigate to the page on an iOS device running iOS 8.0 or later.
3. Fill the input field with characters until you reach the max-length value
4. Move the writing cursor to somewhere in the middle of the entered characters
5. Enter additional characters. This will then make the length of the input value exceed the max-length attribute.

I used the following site to replicate this issue: http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/03-maxlength.html

Should also note that textarea tags behave normally. I only noticed this on input tags.

I've confirmed this only occurs on iOS 8.0 devices.

I've submitted this bug to Apple via the Bug Tracker, but was wondering if anyone else ran into this issue and if so, if they discovered a solution/workaround.

Comment: I received an e-mail from Apple that this is a duplicate of another issue, so they closed my issue. On our project we're using Angular JS, so we ended up writing a directive to basically remake maxlength. Definitely not ideal by any means, but seeing as Apple is very secretive about the status of bugs, it was impossible to know when or if Apple will resolve this. If it helps, the Apple Bug Report number is 17873753, but there's no real way to look up the issue to my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks @Levi L. Even we have raised a bug with Apple regarding this issue, but no response yet. Looks like we will also have to limit the length using JS.